# React Native subscribe to bluetooth event when connected to a peripheral device

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

There are many libraries for BLE
https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager

What is want is to observe the bluetooth status change. One such library is
https://github.com/patlux/react-native-bluetooth-state-manager#readme
It is able to give me the bluetooth PoweredOn or PoweredOff

But nowhere I have found any means to be able to get the observable or event emitter for getting the peripheral device connect or disconnect once the bluetooth is connected to a peripheral device.

I don't want to connect and disconnect from these libraries (react-native-ble-manager, react-native-ble-plx) rather i would like to know if my phone connected/disconnected with any of the device outside of the application where i am trying to observe the event.

If there is something out there using with I can find if a peripheral is connected or disconnected with its id after the bluetooth is connected please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The [react-native-bluetooth-state-manager](https://github.com/patlux/react-native-bluetooth-state-manager) states in it's README:

> The only purpose of this library is to manage the Bluetooth state. Not
> more, not less.
>
> If you need further functionality like connecting and communicating to
> a device, please look at [react-native-ble-plx](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx).

You will find callbacks for connecting or disconnecting in other libraries like your [react-native-ble-manager](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager) or the mentioned [react-native-ble-plx](https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx).

Comment: Yes the only purpose of the library is to show bluetooth state also that the other libraries are able to share feedbacks on connect and disconnect. But my question is that what if my phone connects to a device not from these libraries but outside of the application. Is there any intent for the same? I don't want to connect and disconnect from these libraries rather i would like to know if my phone connected with any device outside of the application. Editing the question for better understanding.